# Error 1265 Loading Data (DATETIME) into MySQL using MYSQL Workbench query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to load a set of data from  a `.txt` file to `MySQL` database. However, i am unable to load the date_time dataset into the table. it is returning `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Can anyone advise me what i am doing wrong?

I have created the following `taxi_movement_data` table into a `taxiapp` schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `taxiapp`.`taxi_movement_data` (
`tracked_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`longitude` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`lattitude` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC));
```

My .txt file sample is as follows.

```
2018-06-01T23:51:09+08:00,103.62926,1.30081
2018-06-01T23:51:09+08:00,103.63598,1.27931
2018-06-01T23:51:09+08:00,103.6375,1.34143
```

My SQL query is as follows

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/uploads/ltasampledata.txt' 
INTO TABLE taxi_movement_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
SET tracked_datetime = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(substring(@tracked_datetime,1,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),INTERVAL 8 HOUR);
```

The result is as follows with the datetime being unable to be loaded. The 'tracked_datetime' returns `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. The longitude, lattitude and id is working fine and as it should.

[Table results after Query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olq2b.png)

Sorry, i am not authorise to load images directly yet on Stackoverflow so it has become a link.

Error Message as follows

```
3 row(s) affected, 9 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'tracked_datetime' at row 1 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns 1048 Column 'tracked_datetime' cannot be null 1265 Data truncated for column 'tracked_datetime' at row 2 1261 Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns 1048 Column 'tracked_datetime' cannot be null 1265 Data truncated for column 'tracked_datetime' at row 3 1261 Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns 1048 Column 'tracked_datetime' cannot be null Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 9 0.078 sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake. In any case, i rectified it by the following. Hopefully, it helps someone down the road.

Add (@tracked_datetime,longitude,lattitude) before setting the tracked_datetime

The SQL query should be as follows.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/uploads/ltasampledata.txt' 
INTO TABLE taxi_movement_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@tracked_datetime,longitude,lattitude)
SET tracked_datetime = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(substring(@tracked_datetime,1,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),INTERVAL 8 HOUR);
```